# Router for personal use

Tags: php, object-oriented, php5

This is router I created for use, however, I wish to refactor this code and make this more robust. I would really appreciate anyone who can:

- Point out how to make this code more robust, clean and flexible in terms of reusability where the user of this module can easily alter the configuration, etc to his/her needs without possibly altering the source code.
- Point out where code can be refactored and possibly ***how***.
- Point out how the code could be made more efficient.

  - Point out places where I have breached any principles of OOP.

Implementation:

```
$router = new Router\Router();
/**
 * The arguments for the method createRoute:
 * First Argument - URI
 * Second Argument - Namespace or Classname of which the method will be executed.
 * Third Argument - The method to be run in the specified namespace/class in the second argument.
 */
$router->createRoute('/', 'PageController', 'showHome');
$result = $router->runRouter();
```

Source Code:

```
<?php
namespace Router;

class Router
{
    private $routes = array();
    private $patternForURIs = '/\{[a-zA-Z0-9]*\}/';

    public function createRoute($uri, $class, $method)
    {
        $result = $this->checkWhetherParametersAreRequired($uri);

        if($result != false) {
            $this->routes[] = [$uri, $class, $method, $result];
            return true;
        }

        $this->routes[] = [$uri, $class, $method];
        return true;
    }

    public function checkWhetherParametersAreRequired($uri)
    {
        if(preg_match_all($this->patternForURIs, $uri, $matches)) {
            return $matches[0];
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function runRouter()
    {
        $routesWhichExpectParameters = array();

        foreach($this->routes as $route) {
            if(isset($route[3])) {
                $routesWhichExpectParameters[] = $route;
            }
            if($route[0] === $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]) {
                return $route;
            }
        }

        foreach($routesWhichExpectParameters as $route) {
            $route[0] = ltrim($route[0], '/');
            $route[0] = explode('/', $route[0]);
            $partsToConfirm = count($route[0]);

            $requestURI = ltrim($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], '/');
            $requestURI = explode('/', $requestURI);
            $partsAvailable = count($requestURI);

            if($partsToConfirm != $partsAvailable) {
                continue;
            }

            $confirmedParts = 0;

            $numberOfParametersToDetect = count($route[3]);
            $numberOfParametersDetected = 0;
            $detectedParameters = array();

            for($iterator = 0; $iterator < $partsToConfirm; $iterator++) {
                if($route[0][$iterator] == $requestURI[$iterator]) {
                    $confirmedParts++;
                    continue;
                } else if(preg_match($this->patternForURIs, $route[0][$iterator])) {
                    $confirmedParts++;
                    $detectedParameters[] = array(
                        $route[3][$numberOfParametersDetected] => $requestURI[$iterator]
                    );

                    $numberOfParametersDetected++;
                    continue;
                }
            }

            if(($numberOfParametersDetected == $numberOfParametersToDetect) && ($partsToConfirm == $confirmedParts)) {
                $route[4] = $detectedParameters;
                return $route;
                break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Will award bounty on the 5th.

Comment: Waiting for more answers

Comment: In order to help make the code more "flexible" we need to understand in what way. For instance, I would consider allowing anonymous functions or closures instead of only allowing class methods… but that may hurt performance.

Comment: @LeviMorrison updated question.

Comment: I don't know PHP. Is the first line `$router = new Router\Router();` and not just `$router = new Router();` ?

Comment: JaDogg you are right. I missed copying the namespace line. Let me fix it.

Comment: Wait, I havent missed it out. it is not vidible

Comment: Fixed it now @JaDogg

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to decide on the *Domain Objects* that represent concepts in your current model.

A `Route` object should [encapsulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)) the data to do with a route. If you look at [Symfony's Route](https://github.com/symfony/Routing/blob/master/Route.php) you'll see that it is simply an object with some properties, getters and setters, and that's about it (apart from a few select helper functions). This is also known as an **Entity**, the end object that you get back.

So, now you know that you want to get back some `Route` entities (`@return Route[]` in phpdoc), you should:

- Create a `Route` object which merely *represents* a route
- Take a look at the [Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)) and create a factory for these

The object API I would then expect to be using would be:

```
$router = new Router(new RouteFactory);
/** @var Route $route */
$route = $router->createRoute('/', 'PageController', 'showHome');
```

Somewhere in the `Router`, it would call `RouteFactory::create($param1, $param2 ...)` to actually make a `Route` object.

Don't expect the user to remember to call `createRoute()` followed by `runRoute()`. If one can't be run before the other, then it looks like you're trying to implement the [builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) creational pattern (which is for *optional* parameters). Your `createRoute()` method should return a `Route` object.

In the context of routing itself, you'll likely want something called a **Resolver**. That is, something you pass a `Route` to, and it instantiates the thing you are routing *to*. In an 'MVC' framework, you have a `ControllerResolver` - so you would create a `Route`, call `ControllerResolver::resolve(Route $route)` and *that* would contain the logic to decide what controller to create based on the contents of the `Route` object (so it'd do things like `class_exists($controllerName)` etc.

It looks like you're trying to design some generic router, but it is doing too many things. Focus on making the following *seperately*:

- An object representing your route (`Route`)
- An object responsible for creating a route from `$_POST` etc (`RouteFactory::createFromGlobals($_POST)` (or similar))
- An object responsible for taking your `Route` and doing what you want to do with it (`ControllerResolver` (or similar))

Separate the actions out that you want to do, contextually, and you'll achieve better [SoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Also, you shouldn't be accessing *any* superglobals (`$_*`) within this class, you should *pass them in* instead. This means that during testing you fake (or 'mock') the data you pass in with relative ease and test that your object still functions as you expect over different scenarios.

Comment: Its a quite good answer but I will wait more. Upvoted.

Comment: Also, if you can add some mock code to explain it would be much easier for me to understand as I find it hard to grasp just raw english.

Comment: I believe that the responsibility to take the route and doing what you have to do with it is the responsibility of the user who uses the library

Comment: @HassanAlthaf It depends what the point of your router is. *Is it* to provide a route to the user? If so, that's fine... but if you're using it in some sort of framework then you won't have an end-user for that specific part of it.

Comment: Not a framework. I am not doing that part because the user may want to call the method statically or instantiate the class and then call the method via the instance. And they may also want to pass in some params.